# Can't declare a hashtable on one line in Java

Tags: java, generics

This works:

```
Hashtable myHT;
myHT = new Hashtable<String, String>();
```

This fails:

```
Hashtable myHT<String,String> = new Hashtable<String,String>();
```

With this error:

```
[javac] /home/me/code/SomeFile.java:10: error: ';' expected
[javac]       Hashtable myHT<String,String> = new Hashtable<String,String>();
```

This fails:

```
Hashtable myHT<String,String>;
myHT = new Hashtable<String,String>();
```

With the error:

```
[javac] /home/me/code/SomeFile.java:10: error: ';' expected
[javac]       Hashtable myHT<String,String>;
```

Also, the behavior is not consistant.  There are other HashTables in the file declared and instantiated on one line, using generics in the declaration, and it works.  What's happening?

Comment: Hashtable <String,String> myHT = new Hashtable<String,String>() works perfect.

Comment: @Dave: On a light note, had something to drink buddy?

Comment: @Bhoot: I've not been spending a lot of time with Java it was an honest mistake.  I don't know why people are downvoting the question and voting to close the question.

Comment: @Dave: Dont worry about it. It happens to all of us. Regarding all the downvoting and flagging - it is the job of the community to maintain the standard of this website. Since this question does not add any value, it is desirable to close this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works:

```
Hashtable<String,String> myHT;
myHT = new Hashtable<String, String>();
```

and so does this:

```
Hashtable<String,String> myHT = new Hashtable<String, String>();
```

And if you're on Java7+, you can take advantage of the improved type inference feature, which allows omitting the explicit setting of type-parameter on the right hand-side of the expression:

```
Hashtable<String, String> myHT = new Hashtable<>();
```

In general, the type-parameter info (`<String, String>`) should be immediately after the type (`Hashtable`). This makes snippets like the following one invalid

```
Hashtable myHT<String,String>;
myHT = new Hashtable<String, String>();
```

because the type-parameter information is not after the type, but after the variable name.

Answer (score 3):

This:
`Hashtable myHT<String,String> = new Hashtable<String,String>();`

Should be:
`Hashtable<String,String> myHT = new Hashtable<String,String>();`

Or if you wanna get fancy:
`Hashtable<String,String> myHT = new Hashtable<>();`

Comment: the fancy is using diamond interface which links the defined data inputs to the construction call (only i added this as more explanation)

Answer (score 2):

How about this line:

```
Hashtable<String,String> myHT = new Hashtable<String,String>();
```